# Use \textcite with et al. and have full names in bibliography

Tags: citing, biber

I want to use a simple way to add references as "Name *et al.* [2]" in the text. Therefore I am using \textcite{reference} with the following configuration:

```
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=ieee,
    minnames=1,
    maxnames=2,
    sorting=nty,
    url=false
]{biblatex}
```

Here is the Latex text:

```
This is a nice text with a reference \textcite{testcitation}.
```

And the Output:

[image]
[image]

However, I want to have the full names of all authors in the bibliography at the end. Is it possible to have "Name et al. [2]" in the text and full author names in the bibliography in the end? If I change the "maxnames=6" in the configuration \textcite will no longer print out *et al.* but will list all the names instead.

SOLUTION (thanks to Ulrike Fischer):

```
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=ieee,
    minnames=1,
    maxcitenames=2,
    maxbibnames=6,
    sorting=nty,
    url=false
]{biblatex}
```

Comment: the biblatex documentation mentions maxcitenames and maxbibnames ...

Comment: wow, great! Thank you very much for this. I overlooked this and I say thank you with a lesson learned from my side.